# Create SWT browser exception

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

how to create an exception for setUrl() method for SWT Browser ? I want to show something that url is wrong or problem with connectivity.

Comment: You'll have to add more detail to your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to check if a website exists before calling `setUrl()`? Do you want to check if the device has a network connection?

Comment: any of exception like page not found or let's say i am calling url but that url's server is stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all you want to do is check if a given URL is available/reachable. In that case, this code will do what you want:

```
private static boolean isReachable(String url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        return responseCode == 200;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just call it before you call `Browser#setUrl()`.